# как получит значение из комбо бокса при выборе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from translate import Translator
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import webbrowser as wb

languages = ["ru", "en", "zh", "ua"]






def introSearch():
    lang = comboExample.get()
    txt = transText.get()
    translator = Translator(to_lang=lang)
    translation = translator.translate(txt)
    copytranslate.insert(0, translation)
    print(translator)


root =  Tk() 
transText = StringVar()
comboExample = StringVar()

comboExample = ttk.Combobox(values=languages)
comboExample.grid(column=0, row=0)
comboExample.current(0)

entrytranslate = Entry(width=25, textvariable=transText)
entrytranslate.grid(column=0, row=1)

copytranslate = Entry(width=25)
copytranslate.grid(column=0, row=3)


copytranslater = Button(command=introSearch)
copytranslater.grid(column=0, row=2)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот уже измененный код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from translate import Translator
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import webbrowser as wb
root =  Tk()
languages = ["ru", "en", "zh", "ua"]
def introSearch():
    lang = comboExample.get()
    txt = transText.get()
    translator = Translator(to_lang=lang)
    translation = translator.translate(txt)
    copytranslate.insert(0, translation)
    print(translator)

comboExample = ttk.Combobox(values=languages)
comboExample.grid(column=0, row=0)
comboExample.current(0)
def doing(e):
           print(comboExample.get())
comboExample.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", doing)
entrytranslate = Entry(width=25, textvariable=transText)
entrytranslate.grid(column=0, row=1)

copytranslate = Entry(width=25)
copytranslate.grid(column=0, row=3)


copytranslater = Button()
copytranslater.grid(column=0, row=2)



root.mainloop()
```

Вы должны будете заменить `print()` на имя переменной